# asp.net membership in asp.net webform website using VS2019

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, asp.net-identity, asp.net-membership

I am testing to use ASP.Net Membership in ASP.Net webform application using VS 2019, By default when i create new webform application it creates identity authentication for application and i want to use ASP.Net Membership in this application

I disabled Owin Identity autheticaltion by adding following setting in webconfig

And also added following setting for ASP.Net Membership

```
  <membership>
      <providers>
        <!--
          ASP.NET Membership is disabled in this template. Please visit the following link https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301889 to learn about the ASP.NET Membership support in this template
        -->
        <clear/>
        <!-- ****ASP.Net Membership Code old not Identity ****-->
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="SQLConnectionString" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="5" applicationName="/"/>

      </providers>
    </membership>
    <profile>
      <providers>
        <!--
          ASP.NET Membership Profile is disabled in this template. Please visit the following link https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301889 to learn about the ASP.NET Membership support in this template
        -->
        <clear/>
        <!-- ****ASP.Net Membership Code old not Identity ****-->
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="SQLConnectionString" applicationName="/"/>


      </providers>
    </profile>
    <roleManager>
      <!--
            ASP.NET Membership Role is disabled in this template. Please visit the following link https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301889 to learn about the ASP.NET Membership support in this template
        -->

      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <!-- ****ASP.Net Membership Code old not Identity ****-->
        <add connectionStringName="SqlConnectionString" applicationName="/" name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider"/>
        <add applicationName="/" name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider"/>
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="?"/>
    </authorization>
```

and below code under `<system.web>`

I am abel to login Using _login.aspx page and it redirects to `default.aspx` under `_admin` directory page but page give me following error `http://localhost:56849/_admin/Default.aspx`

also connection string `SQLConnectionString` is fine as i checked..

> Server Error in '/' Application. Access is denied. Description: An
>   error occurred while accessing the resources required to serve this
>   request. The server may not be configured for access to the requested
>   URL.
>
> Error message 401.2.: Unauthorized: Logon failed due to server
>   configuration.  Verify that you have permission to view this directory
>   or page based on the credentials you supplied and the authentication
>   methods enabled on the Web server.  Contact the Web server's
>   administrator for additional assistance.
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.8.3928.0

I am not sure why this is happening as page is present in `_admin` folder and `_login.aspx` is validating the user & redirecting it correctly.

Any pointer why this could be happening or if i missed any configuration...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by removing following entry in web.config, which i didnt notice before

```
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <!--<remove name="FormsAuthentication"/>-->
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
```

After commenting it ASP.Net membership worked as intended.